# Test the method of a subclass

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-class

I am trying to test that method X of class A calls imported function Y. Class A is a subclass of class B, which should be mocked out.

Class A looks like this:

```
const B = require('./B');
const { Y } = require('../util');
class A extends B {
  constructor() {
    super('/A');
    this.setCors('');
    this.app.post('', this.X.bind(this));
  }

  X(req, res) {
    Y();
  }
}

module.exports = A;
```

The attempt at testing (following [Jest Official Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)):

```
const A = require('../path/to/A');
const B = require('../path/to/B');
jest.mock('../path/to/B', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { setCors: jest.fn(), app: { post: jest.fn() } };
  });
});

test('method X calls function Y', () => {
  (new A()).X();
  expect(Y).toBeCalled();
});
```

This gives the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` about the constructor of A.

Perhaps it is necessary to mock out just the constructor, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The thing you are using for `mockImplementation` doesn't look like a `class`, so I doubt `A` should be able to `extend` it in the first place.

Comment: This is a recommended approach to mocking a class based on the Jest docs.

Comment: It also [says](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#simple-mock-using-module-factory-parameter) "*In order to mock a constructor function, the module factory must return a constructor function. 
**Note: Arrow functions won't work***". The first example at the top of the page seems dubious.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is just for the outer function. Also, it seems to have nearly mocked it correctly, because it is not until the third line of the constructor that the test fails.

Comment: Maybe you are using a transpiler in sloppy mode that messes with the ES6 semantics? In any case, your "constructor" is an arrow function that returns a plain object, not anything inheriting the `X` method from `A.prototype` as it should, that's why the `A` constructor fails (after ignoring that `extends` and `super` can't be used with arrow functions).

Comment: I'm not using a transpiler. The mocking of class `B` seems to have worked, at least partly, because the test can find methods `setCors` and `app.post`. `X` is a method of class `A`, so it is not being inherited from class `B`, so it should be accessible in the scope of the unmocked class `A`.

Comment: I mean that `this instanceof A` will be false. Have you tried using a `class` in the mock?

Comment: I've checked and you are correct about the `this instanceof A`. I then replaced the real class `B` implementation with a very basic class. This means that `instanceof` returns true in the test. However, the whole test fails silently, not even printing a console log from the first line of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Folder structure:

```sh
.
├── A.spec.ts
├── A.ts
├── B.ts
└── util.ts
```

`A.ts`:

```js
import B from './B';
import { Y } from './util';

export default class A extends B {
  constructor() {
    super('/A');
    this.setCors('');
    this.app.post('', this.X.bind(this));
  }

  public X(req, res) {
    Y();
  }
}
```

`B.ts`:

```js
export default class B {
  public app = {
    post(route: string, controller: () => any) {
      //
    }
  };
  private name: string = '';
  private url: string = '';
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  protected setCors(url: string) {
    this.url = url;
  }
}
```

`util.ts`:

```js
export function Y() {
  console.log('I am Y');
}
```

`A.spec.ts`:

```js
import A from './A';
import { Y } from './util';

jest.mock('./util.ts', () => {
  return {
    Y: jest.fn()
  };
});

const a = new A();

describe('A', () => {
  it('should execute function Y correctly', () => {
    const mockedReq = {};
    const mockedRes = {};
    a.X(mockedReq, mockedRes);
    expect(Y).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/52075711/A.spec.ts (5.747s)
  A
    ✓ should execute function Y correctly (8ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 A.ts     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 B.ts     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.623s, estimated 14s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/52075711